# Split column entry into several rows and columns in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table with patent numbers and legal occurences as entries in one column and I would like to split up the entries in several rows. The table looks like this:

Table A:

```
    id                   | patent_number | legal_status
    legstat_EP12345678A1 | EP12345678    | 2019-12-02 some text | 2015-03-26 some more text | 2009-05-16 ...
    legstat_US12345678B2 | US12345678B2  | 2018-08-13 more text | 2016-08-13 even more text | 2004-06-14 ...
```

The last column is a text column, the delimiter between entries is "|". Every such entry starts with a date (yyyy-mm-dd) followed by some text. There may be many such entries in the last column. I would like to generate a table in the following form from Table A.

Table B:

```
    id_b | id_a                 | patent_number | date       | legal_event
    1    | legstat_EP12345678A1 | EP12345678    | 2019-12-02 | some text
    2    | legstat_EP12345678A1 | EP12345678    | 2015-03-26 | some more text
    3    | legstat_EP12345678A1 | EP12345678    | 2009-05-16 | ...
    ...
    10   | legstat_US12345678B2 | US12345678B2  | 2018-08-13 | more text 
    11   | legstat_US12345678B2 | US12345678B2  | 2016-08-13 | even more text 
    12   | legstat_US12345678B2 | US12345678B2  | 2004-06-14 | ...
    ...
```

Unfortunately there is no JSON_TABLE support in MariaDB available. I found some approaches on 
[SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows) , however they did not quite work for me (either no JSON_TABLE support or problems with varying number of entries in the last column). Has anyone an idea how to approach this problem? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: And where does `2009-05-06` come from?  It is not in your sample data.

Comment: It is at the end of the first line of the table, followed by ...

Comment: Looks like you have 2 things that could be the `PRIMARY KEY` in Table A:  `id` and `patent_humber`.

Comment: You can build JSON and put it into a `TEXT` column.